# How to combine and optimize checks for optional's values if present

Tags: java, if-statement, java-8, refactoring, option-type

I have an Immutable class that holds 3 Optional values. I have written a method to validate if the values of them are present, when the optional properties are present. The class looks like the following. I'm wondering how I can refactor these to group them and reduce the number of lines/repetition.

```
public interface Employees {

Optional<Set<String>> names();

Optional<Set<Question>> applicationQuestions();

Optional<Set<Experience>> experienceData();

@Value.Check
default void validateAttributes() {
    names().ifPresent(names -> {
        if (names.stream().anyMatch(StringUtils::isBlank)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Names cannot be empty if present");
        }
    });
    applicationQuestions().ifPresent(applicationQuestions -> {
        if (applicationQuestions.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Application questions cannot be empty if present");
        }
    });
    experienceData().ifPresent(experienceData -> {
        if(experienceData.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Experience data cannot be empty if present");
        }
    });
}

static Employees.Builder builder() {
    return ImmutableEmployees.builder();
}
}
```

Any advice/suggestions to optimize this check and group them together would be much appreciated.

Comment: identify what's common across, `if(<condition>)  throw new IllegalArgumentException(<message>);`..then look if you can create a method for this and would it be helpful for your use case.

Comment: Using `Optional<Set<String>>` is a code smell. Especially for `applicationQuestions()` and `experienceData()`; the set is not allowed to be empty, but is allowed to be absent? Instead of having the three states “not empty”, “absent”, and “invalid” you could get rid of the optional and have the two states “not empty” and “empty (formerly ‘absent’)” and don’t need those checks as the invalid state is impossible.

Comment: The reason for having those 3 states is that this class is in a lambda and users can invoke this through a JSON request. In the Json request, there's Form property, which maps to this class. So the users can pass the property and leave it empty (invalid, hence throw error), or not pass the property (in which case I'll use default values) . Would that justify my approach?

Comment: `Optional` is (usually) ill-suited for instance variables. It’s for return values. No names should be represented by an empty set, not by an empty `Optional`. Same for questions and experience (there may be some weird exception, but not one that warrants an `Optional` that I can see).